# Reactive Cocoa Signal not working

Tags: swift, mvvm, reactive-cocoa

I have this function in my ViewModel, it returns a signal but the inside block is not working, I've tried to add break point but it doesn't break. Here's my code.

```
func executeLoginAPI() -> RACSignal {

            var sessionDataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask = NSURLSessionDataTask()

            return RACSignal.createSignal({
                (subscriber: RACSubscriber!) -> RACDisposable! in

              //I've added break point here but it doesn't break.  
                let manager: APIManager = APIManager.sharedInstance

                let parameters: NSDictionary = ["email": self.email, "password": self.password]

                sessionDataTask = manager.POST(APIAtlas.loginUrl, parameters: parameters, success: {
                    (task: NSURLSessionDataTask!, responseObject: AnyObject!) in

                    print(responseObject as! NSDictionary)
                    subscriber.sendNext(responseObject)
                    subscriber.sendCompleted()
                    }, failure: {
                        (task : NSURLSessionDataTask!, error: NSError!) in

                        /*if let task = task.response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {}*/
                })!

               let dispose: RACDisposable = RACDisposable(block: {
                    print("cancel request!")
                    sessionDataTask.cancel()
                    subscriber.sendCompleted()
                })

                return dispose
            })

    }
```

I access it on my viewController like this

> self.signInViewModel.executeLoginAPI()

Please give me a hand. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because you only created new signal but didn't subscribe. SignalProducer and RACSignal start yourself compute only after subscribe/start.

p.s. if you write on swift used better SignalProducer for this action